# rails new record validation with scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, has-many

Let's assume I have `Projects` and `People` belonging to a `Project`. A `Person` can either be a leader or not and has a scope for this. A `Project` must have at least one leader person or else it is invalid. So I tried this:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people

  validate :has_a_leader

  def has_a_leader
    unless self.people.lead.size > 0
      puts 'Must have at least one leader'
      errors.add(:people, 'Must have at least one leader')
    end
  end
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  scope :lead, -> { where(:is_lead => true) }
end
```

Unfortunately the validation only works with saved records, because the scope is always empty on new records:

```
p = Project.new
p.people.build(:is_lead => true)
=> #<Person ..., is_lead: true>
p.people
=> #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<Person ..., is_lead: true>]>
p.people.lead
=> #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>
p.valid?
'Must have at least one leader'
=> false
```

Another try with another syntax:

```
p = Project.new
p.people.lead.build
=> #<Person ..., is_lead: true>
p.people.lead
=> #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>
p.people
=> #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []> # <-- first syntax at least got something here
p.valid?
'Must have at least one leader'
=> false
```

So it looks like I have to rewrite the validation like this and use the first syntax when creating new projects:

```
  def has_a_leader
    unless self.people.find_all(&:is_lead).size > 0
      puts 'Must have at least one leader'
      errors.add(:people, 'Must have at least one leader')
    end
  end
```

But now I have two places where I have defined what a leader person is: in the validation method and in the scope lambda. I repeat myself. Works, but not the Rails way.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve your problem by adding another association:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :leader, -> { where(is_lead: true) }, class_name: 'Person'
  validates :leader, presence: true
end
```

When you create a `Project` you can set a lead pretty easily:

```
def create
  project = Project.new(params[:project])
  project.leader.new(name: 'Corey') #=> uses the scope to set `is_lead` to `true`
end
```

You still have the `lead` scope duplicated in your `Person` model, but since that's already defined, let's just use it:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :leader, Person.method(:lead), class_name: 'Person'
end
```

This has the upside of making it a lot easier to grab the leader of a project, too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I do it like this, the leader does not show up as a person (at `project.people`). But maybe this is better than nothing. Maybe I should simply create a new `Leader` class with STI from `Person` to make this clear?

Comment: You would want to add the `Person` to both associations. You could also override `leader=` so it calls `people <<` and then passes the call up with `super`. I would *not* complicate this with STI unless a “leader” has a decent amount of different behavior than a `Person`.

Comment: I just see the `is_lead` property is not set to `true` on `project.leader = Person.new(name: 'Corey')` - so after saving the project, the leader vanishes.

Comment: ... did you mean `Person.lead.new(name: 'Corey')`?

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry about that — you're right, you need to reference the scope in the creation of the `Person`. You should be able to do `project.build_leader(name: 'Corey')` directly if that works better with your creation flow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered adding a leader_id or main_leader_id to your projects table?  I understand that your project can have more than one leader, but a potential problem with your implementation is this: suppose you create a project and it has at one person assigned who is a leader, so it's valid -- great.  Later, that person is taken off the project (by changing the Person's project_id attribute).  Unless you put a callback on Person, your Project isn't going to know that it no longer has a leader, and it will be in an invalid state.  That could cause problems if you have other code that assumes that Project is valid and has at least one leader (i.e., my_project.leaders.first.do_something).  If you have something like a main_leader_id, then you can simply validate against that in your Project model (with presence: true), and you can still use a has_many relationship if you need to get all of the leaders.